# Get the path to a node module's directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, npm, ecmascript-6

I want to get some files that reside in a NPM package.

Currently I am using Vue and a validator and I want to grab a localization file to do translation.

I have imported the validator like you would normally do it:

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
```

This package has a `dist` directory which also includes the `locale` directory. This directory has some files that I want.

I could just create a path up to the `node_modules` folder and go all the way down again. But this seems extremely sloppy and error-prone.

Is there a way to get a path to the package directly so I can import the files I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to explicitly climb the directory tree to `node_modules` or use a third party library.

When referencing a module without a positional element, e.g. `"./"`, Node places the cursor of the resolver to within the package's folder (if it exists - it would error otherwise).

For example:

```
import enGB from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/en-GB.js';
```

Answer (score 2):

See the `get-installed-path` module:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-installed-path

From the docs:

> Get installation path where the given package is installed. Works for globally and locally installed packages. Works on Windows too.